# Is it possible to change browser mode without using the IE developer tools?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility

Our application runs fine in IE7 and IE8. We use the `X-UA-Compatible` header to force the browser to use IE7 standards document mode. This is about which rendering engine will be used afai get the picture.
In IE9 however there are a bunch of things which stopped working. In IE9 the document mode is IE7 standards, but the browser mode remains IE9.
When I manually change the browser mode (using the developer tools) to IE7, all is fine again.

Is there a way to programmatically force BROWSER MODE?

Comment: maybe this will help you http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2009/07/27/forcing-ie8-compatibility-mode-in-iis/

Comment: No, this doesn't help me, because that article is about the same as we are doing (setting a X-UA-Compatible header). He explains how to do it using IIS, we do it from code.  
Setting that header only changes the browsers document mode. I'm looking for a way to change the BROWSER MODE without using the developer tools.

Comment: @TweeZz did you find solution, If yes can you pls share it. Thanks.

Comment: nope, this seems to be impossible :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not possible.