# Change IE Mode from 7 to 11 programmatically

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a http URL when launched in IE the Compatibility mode is getting changed to IE7. I want to change it back to IE11. (I can not change the HTML since its not in my control)

I can do this manually through Developer tools (F12).

I want to do this programmatically but i dont know how!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force IE compatibility mode off using tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-using-tags)

Comment: @GSerg I can not make changes to the HTML ! I only have the URL !

Comment: Does the page itself declares IE7 mode, in the meta tag or in the response headers? If so, then probably http://stackoverflow.com/q/9735080/11683, otherwise maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/21142551/11683.

Comment: Thank you @GSerg ! It is resolved !